# Can Chrome "packaged apps" respond to global keyboard commands?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-app, media-keys

I've recently switched from Spotify to Google Music, but miss having a desktop client that responds to keyboard commands. In particular, my laptop has media keys and my fingers keep going to them out of muscle memory.

[image: Media keys found on google images]

To remedy this (and other irritations), I've turned Google Play into a packaged app: "[Package All Areas](https://github.com/tdwright/PackageAllAreas)"

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any documentation on getting packaged apps to respond to keyboard shortcuts. **Is this possible?** Doesn't have to be media keys (if they're tricky), but I'd prefer it if they triggered from anywhere in the OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since chrome 25, there is [chrome.commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands), and since chrome 35 commands can have global scope (see headline 'Scope').

EDIT:
i posted before that the commands api is only available to extensions (and not to 'packaged apps'), because only extensions are explicitly mentioned in the docs - just tried it on a packaged app though, and BOOM - it works :)

EDIT II: although the docs state that "the extension developer is limited to specifying only Ctrl+Shift+[0..9] as global shortcut", i successfully tried using 'MediaPlayPause' as a global shortcut on OSX (thanks to user [Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934239/xan) for pointing me there)

manifest.json:

```
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  },
  "commands": {
    "toggle-feature-foo": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+5"
      },
      "description": "Toggle feature foo",
      "global": true
    }
  }
```

main.js:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    console.log('command:',command);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but have you tried the media keys? They are not listed as allowed global commands.

Comment: Haven't tried, but under 'Usage' the docs say: Supported keys: A-Z, 0-9, Comma, Period, Home, End, PageUp, PageDown, Space, Insert, Delete, Arrow keys (Up, Down, Left, Right) **and the Media Keys (MediaNextTrack, MediaPlayPause, MediaPrevTrack, MediaStop).**

Comment: And further down, _"the extension developer is limited to specifying only Ctrl+Shift+[0..9] as global shortcut"_.

Comment: My fault, i'm sorry. Anyway, the OP stated 'Doesn't have to be media keys' so i guess the answer is valid - but you're right, no media keys.

Comment: Can you test, considering you have a sample all set up?

Comment: hey, i just tried 'MediaPlayPause' and it works too! docs are behind here it seems!

Comment: Which platform did you test? Can you leave a comment about that on https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131612 ?

Comment: posted on google code: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131612#c63

Comment: Thanks. I guess you can update your answer then. Upvoting in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not possible in the platform. There is a work in progress, tracked by [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131612), to support Media keys.

If you absolutely want to do it now and don't care about complex user requirements, Boris Smus had [a good take on this](http://smus.com/chrome-media-keys-revisited/), using a native key interceptor that sends the intercepted command through a websocket to the app (extension in his post, but easily adaptable to an app).